# Not a valid icon name for family "material-community" when trying to use react-native-vector-icons

Tags: react-native, react-native-vector-icons

I am trying to use the `kayaking` icon that is part of the `MaterialCommunityIcons`, but that icon seems to not exist or something.

However, I can get other icons to work. Looking at this site [react-native-vector-icons directory](https://oblador.github.io/react-native-vector-icons/), I see that `kayaking` is in fact an icon. It also says so here at this link: [Github icon directory](https://github.com/oblador/react-native-vector-icons/blob/master/glyphmaps/MaterialCommunityIcons.json).

So why can't I get the icon to work?

This is how I have tried:

```
import Icon from "react-native-vector-icons/MaterialCommunityIcons";

// DOES NOT WORK
<Icon name="kayaking" />

// BUT THE BELOW DOES WORK
<Icon name="access-point" />
```

I also tried this:

```
import { MaterialCommunityIcons } from "@expo/vector-icons";

// DOES NOT WORK
<MaterialCommunityIcons name="kayaking"/>

// BUT THE BELOW DOES WORK
<MaterialCommunityIcons name="access-point"/>
```

Can someone please tell me what is going on? This is so simple, yet it seems like the `kayaking` icon no longer exists...